# MVC FileStreamResult causing internal server error on Windows Phone

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC action that returns FileStreamResult as below

```
Public Function Download(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
     Dim document As Document = db.Documents.Find(id)
     If document IsNot Nothing AndAlso document.Position.License.IdLicense = SessionManager.User.IdLicense Then
          Return New FileStreamResult(New MemoryStream(document.Data), document.MimeType)
      Else
          Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
      End If
End Function
```

This is working in my desktop with win 8.1 but not on my windows phone. The result is internal server error http status code 500.

Is there something wrong in the code?

Comment: A try/catch, some logging or detailed HTTP response may help (a lot)...

Comment: True... Something to do with the session variables I'm using. For some reason they are null in windows phone environment but work in desktop.